# How to add an item to an array to show in lightning component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience

I have an attibute `<aura:attribute name="projectResources" type="Contact[]" />` and iterate it by `<aura:iteration>`. When user clicks a button I want to add a new element to the array. When I use `projectResources.push(selectedResource);` it adds the element as a **Proxy** and do not apply the element inside of `<aura:iteration>`. To workaround I use `projectResources = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(projectResources));`. Example:

```
var projectResources = component.get("v.projectResources");

// Workaround to extract array from Proxy.
projectResources = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(projectResources));        

projectResources.push(newResource);
component.set("v.projectResources", projectResources);
```

I don't like this `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())` approach. Is there any better way?

Comment: Hi Mikhail, have you already done the trailhead module that covers this topic? https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/lex_dev_lc_basics

Comment: I've directly used `get`, `push`, `set` to add new entries to an `<aura:iteration>` with the HTML updating as expected. Not sure what you mean by "proxy" here.  If you are starting from no items worth adding `if (!projectResources) projectResources = [];` to start with an empty array not null or undefined.

Comment: @glls, yes, I passed the trailhead module. May be I missed something there... Can you point me to a place where it explains how to add a new item to an existing `<aura:attribute type="anySObjectArray">` to show it inside of `<aura:iteration>`?

Comment: Make sure your aura:iteration items attribute binds projectResources ala {!v.projectResources}

Answer (score -1):

```
({
loop : function(component, event, helper) {
 var spaceList = component.get("v.spaceTypeList");
var detail = component.get("v.detailRecord");
var newlst =[];
 for(i in spaceList){
    console.log(i);
    var space = spaceList[i];
    var detailtemp = {};
    detailtemp = detail;
    detailtemp.Name = space;
 console.log("detail space subset "+detailtemp.Name);
    newlst.push(detailtemp);
    console.log("value after iteration"+i+JSON.stringify(newlst));
  }
component.set("v.acclst",newlst);
```